# Problem with setting two different ranges on visible rows, with different filters

Tags: excel, vba, filter, range

I m trying to create a vba file in excel to manage sales
I have a table to save Products and one for Invoice

To calculate total price for all sales in my report userform, I Use worksheetfunction.sumproduct.... and it works well.

Then I want to get the Total value in special period of time. So I filter my Invoice sheet, and set a range on visible cells, and use  worksheetfunction.sumproduct.... in my Range and it works well again...

But Now I want to add new condition, for product cod. again, I filter my Invoice sheet, and set another range on visible cells, and use  worksheetfunction.sumproduct.... this time the second range, just get one record. But the filtered sheet has more records visible.

hope I could explain the problem, correctly.

Thank you for your help.

| ID | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product 1 |
| 2 | Product 2 |

| Rec | Factor | ProductNum | Qty | Price | Desc | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 250000 |  | 1401/10/16 |
| 12 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 5000000 |  | 1401/10/16 |
| 21 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 250000 |  | 1401/11/17 |
| 22 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 5000000 |  | 1401/11/17 |
| 31 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 250000 |  | 1401/11/25 |
| 32 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 5000000 |  | 1401/11/25 |
| 41 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 5500000 |  | 1401/11/30 |
| 42 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 250000 |  | 1401/11/30 |
| 51 | 5 | 1 | 4 | 250000 |  | 1401/12/05 |
| 61 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 5000000 |  | 1401/12/10 |

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If SD = Empty Then SD = "14010101"
    If FD = Empty Then FD = "14011229"
    
    EOR = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range("A1:G" & EOR).AutoFilter 7, "<=" & FD, xlAnd, ">=" & SD
    Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:G" & EOR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    
    TextBox1.Text = Format(WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Rng.Columns(4), Rng.Columns(5)), "#,##0")
    TextBox2.Text = Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng.Columns(4)), "#,##0")
    
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Rng.AutoFilter 3, Val(ComboBox1.Value)
    Set NewRng = Sheet1.Range("A2:G" & EOR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    TextBox3.Text = Format(WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(NewRng.Columns(4), NewRng.Columns(5)), "#,##0")
    TextBox4.Text = Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(NewRng.Columns(4)), "#,##0")
    
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The second SumProduct and Sum don't work because newRng is a non-contiguous range with areas. The Solution it to summate each area in a loop.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim SD, FD, EOR, Rng, newRng
    
    If SD = Empty Then SD = "14010101"
    If FD = Empty Then FD = "14011229"
    
    EOR = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range("A1:G" & EOR).AutoFilter 7, "<=" & FD, xlAnd, ">=" & SD
    
    Dim a As Range, v1, v2, v3, v4
    Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:G" & EOR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each a In Rng.Areas
         v1 = v1 + WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(a.Columns(4), a.Columns(5))
         v2 = v2 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(a.Columns(4))
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = Format(v1, "#,##0")
    TextBox2.Text = Format(v2, "#,##0")
    
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Rng.AutoFilter 3, Val(ComboBox1.Value)
    Set newRng = Sheet1.Range("A2:G" & EOR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each a In newRng.Areas
         v3 = v3 + WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(a.Columns(4), a.Columns(5))
         v4 = v4 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(a.Columns(4))
    Next
    
    TextBox3.Text = Format(v3, "#,##0")
    TextBox4.Text = Format(v4, "#,##0")
   
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    
End Sub
```